# Loop runs infinite times

Tags: c

I was trying to print the last digits of the numbers from 1 till 100 in this format
1
2
.
.
9    9
1    0    0

The code i had written in  is

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
int last_digit,i;
for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
  while(i!=0)
        {
        last_digit=i%10;
        printf("Last_digit=>%d\t",last_digit);
        i=i/10;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

But this runs into a infinite loop whenever i try to execute it. Could you tell me where the problem lies ?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) to *observe* the value of `i` while running your program *step by step*

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `while` loop decreases `i` by dividing it by 10, so it never reaches 100. Try using another variable for the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int last_digit,i,j;
for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
   j = i;
   while(j!=0)
   {
      last_digit=j%10;
      printf("Last_digit=>%d\t",last_digit);
      j=j/10;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are decreasing `i` in every iteration in this line of the inner while loop

```
i=i/10;
```

The condition of the inner while loop explicitly states that after the loop, `(i != 0) == false` in other words, the inner while loop enforces `i == 0` after the loop. Therefore, `i` remains smaller than 100 and your loop never finishes.

To solve your problem, use another iteration variable in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your assignment correctly then what you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main( void )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    int i;


    for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )
    {
        int x = i;
        int n = 1;

        while ( x / ( n * Base ) != 0 ) n *= Base;

        do
        {
            printf( "%d ", x / n );
            x %= n;
            n /= Base;
        } while ( n != 0 );

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
1 5 
1 6 
1 7 
1 8 
1 9 
2 0 
//...
9 0 
9 1 
9 2 
9 3 
9 4 
9 5 
9 6 
9 7 
9 8 
9 9 
1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print **only last digit** of number, you can print num%10

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        printf("Last_digit=>%d\t",i%10);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you are trying to print **each digit** of number then:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        j=i;
        while(j>0)
        {
             printf("digit=>%d\n",j%10);
             j/=10;
         }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Please try to be clear in your questions.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the while loop i id zero gets incremented by the for loop I.e one. Then the for loop test is applied. Hence infinite loop